# Allegro 5 isn't working

Tags: c++, installation, allegro, allegro5

I have just started programming in allegro, but the first simple program i wrote to check it is in working order returns the error:

> "Unhandled exception at 0x0F4C590B (allegro-5.0.7-monolith-md-debug.dll) in C++ Setup.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000."

I have looked for solutions but i cant find any, and yes, i have made sure it's 5.0.7 i have installed and linked to.

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing Allegro 5 and still do not know where the problem lies.

Comment: reinstalling isn't going to fix access violation error... try a debugger...

Answer (score 0):

Access Violation errors are very rare and always related to the individual computer on which they occur.  They are not errors in the ExpressMaintenance software but rather the result of something not functioning right on the system that causes the program to lose its place in memory.  Usually an Access Violation results following some other error and it is the preceding error that is of significance.

Again, Access Violation errors are rare and always relate to the individual computer operating software or settings.  The exact cause of the error can be difficult to find.  Common causes typically are one one of the following:

1. Corrupt or insufficient version of Windows.
2. Insufficient RAM memory or system requirements.
3. Old or bad version of Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC). See below.
4. Insufficient virtual memory allocated for large queries and data in memory.

[Source](http://www.expresstechnology.com/support/knowledge-base/70-updates-a-troubleshooting/126-what-should-i-do-if-i-get-an-access-violation)